# Can I run the #new and #create methods of my #game controller on my home page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am creating a counter for a card game and would like to have a "New Game" button directly on my homepage, meaning without passing on the #new-game view.
My #game model doesn't need any information to be created (e.g: name...) so no form on a #new-game view needed to create it. The app is currently working but I have to pass on my #new-game view before a #game can be created.

I am struggling with the logic of the #new and #create actions of my #game controller taking place on my #home view (#pages controller).

Can anybody help ?

Thanks a lot

Here's my #game controller :

```
  def new
    @game = Game.new
    @game.biddings.build
  end

  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
    @game.save

    redirect_to game_path(@game)
  end
```

My #page controller :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:home]

  def home
  end
end
```

And my #home view :

```
<div class="full-height home-colors">
  <div class="abs-center">
    <h1>BIENVENU SUR COINCH'COUNT !</h1>

    <p>Coinch'Count est un compteur de points simplifié pour la coinche.</p>

    <%= link_to 'Nouvelle partie', new_game_path, class: 'regular-btn' %>

    <%= link_to 'Liste de toute les parties', games_path, class: 'transp-btn' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea being to have the first link_to directly creating a #game instance and redirecting to the #game show.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I run the #new and #create methods of my #game controller on my
> home page?

**No.** Each request in Rails will only ever run one controller action so its a nonsensical goal.
What you really want to do is just add a form or a link on your `pages/home.html.erb` view that sends a POST request to `/games`.

You can do this with [`button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) which creates a form that just contains a single button:

```
# these all generate the exact same HTML
<%= button_to("Create game", Game.new) %>
<%= button_to("Create game", games_path, method: :post) %>
<%= button_to("Create game", controller: :games, action: :create) %>
```

This will work even if the client has turned JS off as its just a standard HTML form.

You can also use [`link_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to) with the `method` option:

```
# these all generate the exact same HTML
<%= link_to("Create game", Game.new, method: :post) %>
<%= link_to("Create game", games_path, method: :post) %>
<%= link_to("Create game", controller: :games, action: :create, method: :post) %>
```

This adds a `data-method="POST"` attribute to the link. Rails UJS defines a event handler for elements with this data attribute which will create a form and post it to the server so that a POST request is sent instead of GET.

If there are any JS errors that prevent the handler from working (like Rails UJS not being loaded) the default browser action of sending a GET request will happen instead so make sure you check the browser console if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare your link as a "post", and use the creation path `games_path` :

```
<%= link_to 'Nouvelle partie', games_path, method: :post, class: 'regular-btn' %>
```

It will work because, as you said, you don't have any mandatory parameter:

> My #game model doesn't need any information to be created

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried what you said but now I am being redirected to my #games index when I click the button and no new #game seem to be created. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Did you put the ", method: :post" in your `link_to`?

Comment: If so, try to follow these steps to make it work: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#installation-using-the-jquery-rails-gem (install "jquery-rails" gem and require it in your `application.js`)

Comment: I did add the method: :post and followed the whole steps you send without a different results :/ ```    <%= link_to 'Nouvelle partie', games_path, method: :post, class: 'regular-btn' %>```

Comment: It's really strange, it should work :/
Otherwise, you can always create a new route in your `config/routes.rb` file: `get 'create_game', action: :create, controller: 'games'`. And change your link into: `<%= link_to 'Nouvelle partie', create_game_path, class: 'regular-btn' %>`

Comment: @romainsalles That's really bad advice as GET requests should not create or alter resources. Consider what happens when the user presses the back button in the browser for an example of why its such a bad idea.